# Is it safe to use $_SESSION to store temporarily a user provided value under multi-step form processing

Tags: 7, forms, ajax, security, sessions

I have a form which contains an AJAX button press callback. Upon pressing this AJAX button, I want to store temporarily a form element's value before fully processing all the data upon pressing main form submimission button. On the meanwhile, how do I store that particular field value? Is it fine to achieve this using `$_SESSION`? Is this secure? Does it work flawlessly under Drupal 7, or is there a better alternative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `$form_state` is passed by reference to the form builder and to the form validation/submission handlers, and to the AJAX callback, in this case you can just use `$form_state`. It is not passed to the browser, but stored in the database, so there are less chances its content could be altered by malicious code. (This doesn't mean the content of `$_SESSION` is less secure.)

Traditionally, `$form_state['storage']` was used to contain all those values a module needed to temporary storage, but see what [`drupal_build_form()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21form.inc/function/drupal_build_form/7.x) says. (Emphasis is mine.)

> **storage**: `$form_state['storage']` is not a special key, and no specific support is provided for it in the Form API. By tradition it was the location where application-specific data was stored for communication between the submit, validation, and form builder functions, **especially in a multi-step-style form**. Form implementations may use any key(s) within `$form_state` (other than the keys listed here and other reserved ones used by Form API internals) for this kind of storage. The recommended way to ensure that the chosen key doesn't conflict with ones used by the Form API or other modules is to use the module name as the key name or a prefix for the key name. For example, the Node module uses `$form_state['node']` in node editing forms to store information about the node being edited, and this information stays available across successive clicks of the "Preview" button as well as when the "Save" button is finally clicked.

Answer (score 2):

Drupal has an [Ajax framework](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21ajax.inc/group/ajax/7.x) for this use case. Use $form_state to store values. The API page about the Ajax framework contains a use of $form_state.